# SWIFTUI: .overlay breaks alignment

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment, ios16

I have this bit of code below where I'm trying to have a rectangle centered in the screen, where I overlay a text outupt from some function and a share button. The concept works, except that when I add the .overlay, the "text box" (the rectangle with the text and share button overlayed to it) lose the centered alignment and they move to the left.If I remove the .overlay, the rectangle is centered but the content remains behind it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
GeometryReader { geometry in  // Debug alignment
    VStack(alignment: .center) {  //TextBox

        Rectangle()
         .fill(Color.cyan)
         .cornerRadius(20)
         .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.75, height: 200, alignment: .center)
         .overlay(
            ScrollView {
                HStack(alignment: .top){
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        
                        Text(responseText)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                            .layoutPriority(2)
                    }
                    
                    ShareLink(item: responseText){
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                        
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
    )
                
    } //Vstack Top
}  //Geo Reader
```

I tried to center the recantgle while using the .overlay to put the conetent on top of it but the centered aligment gets lost. I also tried to use a ZStack instead of a .overlay but the content remains hidden behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GeometryReader` positions its children at its top left. The `VStack` child of `GeometryReader` hugs its children—in this case, its single child, which is a `Rectangle` with a fixed frame.

Put the `Rectangle` in a container that expands to the size of the enclosing `GeometryReader` and centers the `Rectangle` within the expanded size.

For example, add a `frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` modifier on the `VStack`:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in  // Debug alignment
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.cyan)
            etc. etc.
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

Result:

[image: iPhone screen shot showing a blue rounded rectangle in the middle of the screen with text and a share button overlaid on it.]

But if you don't have anything else to put in the `VStack`, you can remove it and put the `frame` modifier directly on the `Rectangle`, after the `overlay`:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in  // Debug alignment
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.cyan)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.75, height: 200)
        .overlay(
            ScrollView {
                HStack(alignment: .top){
                    Text(responseText)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)

                    ShareLink(item: responseText) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                             .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```